# decode json as html

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

So I'm building a web application and I have an ajax request that pings a database (or database cache) and echos back a big thing of json. I'm totally new to json, and when the php pulls from the database I echo json_encode($databaseResults), then it shows up in my html page as a long string. My question is, how do I convert it and pull out the pieces I need into a nice format?

Thanks!

The Json result that was in the page looks like:

"[{\"currentcall\":\"1\",\"timecalled\":\"15:30\",\"etaTime\":\"15:35\",\"departmentID\":\"1\",\"memberID\":\"1\",\"callinnum\":\"1\",\"location\":\"Fire House\",\"billed\":\"N\",\"date\":\"2\\/12\\/11\",\"firstName\":\"Phil\",\"lastName\":\"asdf\",\"email\":\"pasdf@gmail.com\",\"homephone\":\"+19111111111\",\"cellphone\":\"+11234567891\",\"cellphone2\":null,\"workphone\":null,\"phonenumber5\":null,\"phonenumber6\":null,\"streetAddress\":\"10 asdfnt Dr\",\"city\":\"\",\"username\":\"pgsdfg\",\"password\":\"0623ab6b6b7dsasd3834799fbf2a08529d\",\"admin\":\"Y\",\"qualifications\":\"Interior\",\"rank\":null,\"cpr\":null,\"emt\":null,\"training\":null,\"datejoined\":null,\"dateactive\":null,\"state\":\"DE\",\"zip\":\"51264\",\"pending\":\"NO\",\"defaultETA\":\"7\",\"apparatus\":\"asdKE-286\"}]"

There can be multiple results... this is only one result

EDIT:

Basically, I'm trying to pass a bunch of rows in an array into an html file, and take out only the data I need and format it. I don't know if json is the best way to do this or not, just one solution I came up with. So if anyone has a better solution that would be awesome.

Edit2: 
This is the jquery I have that makes the request, the php just has echo json_encode ($DBResults);

```
function getResponder(){
    var responders = $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url: "/index.php/callresponse/get_responders",
            success: function(html){
                $("#ajaxDiv").html(html);   
            }
    });

setTimeout("getResponder()", 10000);
}
```

Comment: How does databaseResults look like? As I understand it's just a string am I correct? If you're only returning a string what's the point of using json? The benefit of json is that you can pass several values in a string and then convert them to an object/array on the javascript side.

Comment: From the looks of your code example you should pass plain html from your php script and not JSON. If you want to use json you might want to use the jQuery getJSON function. But if you go with the json alternative you'll have to define where you want to print the data you can't just set the innerHTML of #ajaxDiv to the json string and neither the object.

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks. I'll look into the jQuery getJson or just put it in as straight html

Comment: Are you sure you aren't return to many values?  Do you really want to put password hash and so on in the table? You're returning no less then 35 values. I were going to write an example using your data but I'll wait and see if that's really what you want in the table.

Comment: Hmm, I gues I don't need all of that. I'll adjust my sql statement acordingly, but I really just need, firstName, lastName, Location, defaultETA, and apparatus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you flagged this as jquery I assume that you're using jQuery. If you're only going to get the one string you can skip the json part and use jQuery .load() like this `$('#result').load('ajax/test.php');` that will load the contents from ajax/test.php into #result

However if you want to use json you can take a look over at [getJSON on the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). You can also use the [jQuery parseJSON function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) which will return the json an javascript object containing the jsonData.

Here's an example how you can use parseJSON

```
var object = $.praseJSON(jsonString); //jsonString is the string containing your actual json data
alert(object.location) //Will alert "Fire House" with the given json string
```

Here's an example of how you can use getJSON in the same way

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.php', function(object) {
  alert(object.location); //Will alert "Fire House" with the given json string
});
```

If you want to pass parameters as well you can do it like this

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.php', 
    { 
        Param1 : "Value1", 
        Param2 : "value2" 
    },
    function(object) {
        alert(object.location);  //Will alert "Fire House" with the given json string
    }
);
```

If you are trying to send json from javascript to php you can use

```
$jsonArray = jsonDecode($_GET['key']);
```

Of course if you're using post you'll write $_POST instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have to parse the data into a JSON object, then you can use properties of the object as you wish.

Without seeing the specifics, I can tell you that you'll need to use the JSON object to parse the text.  See more here: http://www.json.org

```
var obj = JSON.parse(ajaxResponseText);
```

Comment: Not all browsers support native JSON.parse()

Comment: True.  However, the answer was intended to be general, as the specifics are not available.  The link contains a link to a downloadable JS library that provides JSON.parse() functionality on all browsers.  https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: your link is broken

Answer (score 0):

You should use php function [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) which will give you an object or array with all the properties.

Then you should iterate recursively through this object and add the content of the properties to a string, which should be your final HTML.

Comment: hmm, so if I do json_decode it'll pass me an array, then I can use php to access everything in the array?

Comment: Wait are you trying to send json from javascript to php or the other way around. As I understood from the initial post you were trying to send json to javascript and not the other way around.

Comment: See my edit. Basically I need to get info from a database into an html file. I'm not sure the best possible way